# Can't reproduce cpu cache-miss

Tags: cpu-cache

Good day!

I'm reading this wonderful article: [What every programmer should know about memory](http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/). Right now I'm trying to figure out how CPU caches work and reproduce the experiment with cache misses. The aim is reproduce performance degradation when amount of accessed data rises (figure 3.4). I wrote a little program, that should reproduce degradation, but it doesn't. The performance degradation appears after I allocate more than 4Gb of memory, and I don't understand why. I think it should appear when 12 or maybe 100 of MB allocated. Maybe the program is wrong and I miss something? I use

```
Intel Core i7-2630QM
L1: 256Kb
L2: 1Mb
L3: 6Mb
```

Here is the GO listing.

*main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
)

const (
    n0 = 1000
    n1 = 100000
)

func readInt64Time(slice []int64, idx int) int64

func main() {
    ss := make([][]int64, n0)
    for i := range ss {
        ss[i] = make([]int64, n1)
        for j := range ss[i] {
            ss[i][j] = int64(i + j)
        }
    }
    var t int64
    for i := 0; i < n0; i++ {
        for j := 0; j < n1; j++ {
            t0 := readInt64Time(ss[i], rand.Intn(n1))
            if t0 <= 0 {
                panic(t0)
            }
            t += t0
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("Avg time:", t/int64(n0*n1))
}
```

*main.s*

```
// func readInt64Time(slice []int64, idx int) int64
TEXT ·readInt64Time(SB),$0-40
    MOVQ    slice+0(FP), R8
    MOVQ    idx+24(FP), R9
    RDTSC
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    MOVQ    AX, R10
    MOVQ    (R8)(R9*8), R8 // Here I'm reading the memory
    RDTSC
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    SUBQ    R10, AX
    MOVQ    AX, ret+32(FP)
    RET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who interested. I reproduced the 'cache-miss' behavior. But the performance degradation was not so dramatic as the article describes. Here is the final benchmark listing:

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "runtime/debug"
)

func readInt64Time(slice []int64, idx int) int64

const count = 2 << 25

func measure(np uint) {
    n := 2 << np
    s := make([]int64, n)
    for i := range s {
        s[i] = int64(i)
    }
    t := int64(0)
    n8 := n >> 3
    for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
        // Intex is 64 byte aligned, since cache line is 64 byte
        t0 := readInt64Time(s, rand.Intn(n8)<<3)
        t += t0
    }
    fmt.Printf("Allocated %d Kb. Avg time: %v\n",
        n/128, t/count)
}

func main() {
    debug.SetGCPercent(-1) // To eliminate GC influence
    for i := uint(10); i < 27; i++ {
        measure(i)
        runtime.GC()
    }
}
```

**main_amd64.s**

```
// func readInt64Time(slice []int64, idx int) int64
TEXT ·readInt64Time(SB),$0-40
    MOVQ    slice+0(FP), R8
    MOVQ    idx+24(FP), R9
    RDTSC
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    MOVQ    AX, R10
    MOVQ    (R8)(R9*8), R11 // Read memory
    MOVQ    $0, (R8)(R9*8) // Write memory
    RDTSC
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    SUBQ    R10, AX
    MOVQ    AX, ret+32(FP)
    RET
```

I disabled garbadge collector to illiminate its infuence and made 64B index alignment, since my processor has 64B cache line.

The benchmark result is:

```
Allocated 16 Kb. Avg time: 22
Allocated 32 Kb. Avg time: 22
Allocated 64 Kb. Avg time: 22
Allocated 128 Kb. Avg time: 22
Allocated 256 Kb. Avg time: 22
Allocated 512 Kb. Avg time: 23
Allocated 1024 Kb. Avg time: 23
Allocated 2048 Kb. Avg time: 24
Allocated 4096 Kb. Avg time: 25
Allocated 8192 Kb. Avg time: 29
Allocated 16384 Kb. Avg time: 31
Allocated 32768 Kb. Avg time: 33
Allocated 65536 Kb. Avg time: 34
Allocated 131072 Kb. Avg time: 34
Allocated 262144 Kb. Avg time: 35
Allocated 524288 Kb. Avg time: 35
Allocated 1048576 Kb. Avg time: 39
```

I run this bench many times, and it gave me similar results for every run. If I removed read and write ops from asm code, then I got 22 cycles for all allocations, so this time difference is memory access time. As you can see, the first time shift is at 512 Kb allocation size. Just one cpu cycle, but it's very stable. The next time change at 2 Mb. At 8 Mb there is the most significant time change, but it still 4 cycles, and we out of cache at all.

After all that tests I see that there is no dramatic cost for the cache-miss. It still significant, since the time difference is 10-15 times, but not 50-500 times as we saw in the article. Maybe todays memory significantly faster, than 7 years ago? Looks promising =) Maybe after the next 7 years there will be architertures with no cpu caches at all. We'll see.

EDIT:
As @Leeor mentioned, RDTSC instruction has no serializing behaviour and there can be out of order execution. I tried RDTSCP instruction instead:

**main_amd64.s**

```
// func readInt64Time(slice []int64, idx int) int64
TEXT ·readInt64Time(SB),$0-40
    MOVQ    slice+0(FP), R8
    MOVQ    idx+24(FP), R9
    BYTE $0x0F; BYTE $0x01; BYTE $0xF9; // RDTSCP
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    MOVQ    AX, R10
    MOVQ    (R8)(R9*8), R11 // Read memory
    MOVQ    $0, (R8)(R9*8) // Write memory
    BYTE $0x0F; BYTE $0x01; BYTE $0xF9; // RDTSCP
    SHLQ    $32, DX
    ORQ     DX, AX
    SUBQ    R10, AX
    MOVQ    AX, ret+32(FP)
    RET
```

Here what I got with this changes:

```
Allocated 16 Kb. Avg time: 27
Allocated 32 Kb. Avg time: 27
Allocated 64 Kb. Avg time: 28
Allocated 128 Kb. Avg time: 29
Allocated 256 Kb. Avg time: 30
Allocated 512 Kb. Avg time: 34
Allocated 1024 Kb. Avg time: 42
Allocated 2048 Kb. Avg time: 55
Allocated 4096 Kb. Avg time: 120
Allocated 8192 Kb. Avg time: 167
Allocated 16384 Kb. Avg time: 173
Allocated 32768 Kb. Avg time: 189
Allocated 65536 Kb. Avg time: 201
Allocated 131072 Kb. Avg time: 215
Allocated 262144 Kb. Avg time: 224
Allocated 524288 Kb. Avg time: 242
Allocated 1048576 Kb. Avg time: 281
```

Now I see that big difference between cahce and RAM access. The time is actualy 2 times lower than in the article, but it's predictable, since memory frequency is as twice higher.

Comment: In the answer part are you really describing the solution of above problem ?

Comment: The problem was that I couldn't repeat the experiment, described in the article. Eventually I managed the problem, and wrote how I did it, what I changed and what confuced me at first aproach. So, yes, I described the solution of above problem.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed doesn't produce the attempted observation, it's not clear exactly what your benchmark does - are you accessing randomly within the range? are you measuring access latency per single access?

It seems that your benchmark will incur a constant overhead per time measurement that is not amortized, so you're basically measuring the function call time (which is constant).
Only when the memory latency become large enough to pass that overhead (when you access the DRAM at 4GB), you actually start getting meaningful measurements.

You should switch to measuring the time over the entire loop (over `count` iterations) and divide.

Comment: I can't switch to measuring the time over the entire loop, because of contexts swithces, function call overheads and not synchronized TSC on different cores. Instead I measure memory access time in place in CPU cycles with RDTSC instruction. With this aproach there is greatly less chance that all mentioned factors can affect my benchmark.

Comment: And, look below, I reproduced cache-miss behaviour. It's stable but not so expressed as I might expect.

Comment: It's not expressed, it's not there - you don't have any jump around your L1 cache size. This is because all these latencies are dominated by your measuring overhead (RDTSC is serializing and extremely not efficient if called too often), so you must amortize. Don't worry about context switches, they're not that frequent.

Comment: I don't agree with you. RDTSC latency exactly 22 cycles. It appears regardlessly allocation size if I eliminate reading and writing memory instuctions. If reading and writing instrutions are there, then it depends. Actualy RDTSC is NOT serializing and I'll try to use RDTSCP instead to look if there will be difference. And what is that mean 'extremely not efficient if called too often'? I don't need performance, I need to see the actual RAM access latency. May be there is an out of order execution since RDTSC is not serialized, but if it's not, then I think my measurements are correct.

Comment: Ok. I checked it out. Looks like there is really out of order execution. Results with RDTSCP more expressive, than with RDTSC. I'll resume with experiments and will publish the results.

Comment: Yes, i meant RDTSC requires being called together with CPUID or other serializing instruction, RDTSCP improves things only a little, but you still need to amortize if you want to be able to distinguish between L1/L2/L3 latencies.

Comment: Actually RDTSCP improves things significantly. I edited my answer, so you can look at new results. I don't understand what does mean 'amortize'.

Comment: The new results are still flat around the L1 and L2 sizes, which doesn't make any sense. Amortizing in this context means measuring time around the inner loop - the time per iteration will be the total time divided by the number of iterations - that's how you avoid paying the measurement penalty thousands of times.